# Is it possible to save Hadoop Counter data into HDFS?

Tags: hadoop

I would like to use counter data programmatically. 
Is this possible? The data can be saved in HDFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the main function of your job, after job is finished you can programmatically take counters from the job and then save them into HDFS.  
So your code in the main will looks like this:

```
    ...
job.waitForCompleteion();
// read counters looks something like this:
 Counters c = job.getCounters();
 Counter cnt = c.findCounter("YouCounterName");
 // counter has getName() and getValue() methods    
...
// save to hdfs 
...
```